# Prove a function $f_\sigma\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Define $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ be the space that contains all bounded continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}$ that has continuous derivatives of all orders. Suppose $K\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ s.t. $K(x)=0$ for $|z|>1$, and $f$ is a bounded measurable real function on $\mathbb{R}$. For each $\sigma>0$, let

$f_\sigma(x):=\int_\mathbb{R}f(x+\sigma z)K(z)\,dz$

I want to prove that $f_\sigma\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$.

My approach so far: we can rewrite $f_\sigma(x)=\frac{1}{\sigma}\int_\mathbb{R}f(z)K(\frac{z-x}{\sigma})\,dz$ by change of variables. Somehow if I can prove $f_\sigma\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$, then I can repeat the arguments to prove that $f_\sigma\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$. The hint told me to use a dominated convergence argument, but I don't see how this could apply to the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will show you how to apply the dominated convergence theorem. First, we want to prove that $f_\sigma$ is differentiable, and then we repeat the process, to prove that it is in $C^\infty(\mathbb R)$

So, for the beginning consider a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ such that $x_n\rightarrow x$ and take the quotient:
$$\dfrac{f_\sigma(x_n)-f_\sigma(x)}{x_n-x}=\dots=\frac{1}{\sigma}\int_\mathbb R f(z)\dfrac{K(\frac{z-x_n}{\sigma})-K(\frac{z-x}{\sigma})}{x_n-x}dz$$
From the mean value theorem, $\forall n\in \mathbb N, \exists y_n$ between $x_n$ and $x$ such that:
$$\dfrac{K(\frac{z-x_n}{\sigma})-K(\frac{z-x}{\sigma})}{x_n-x}=\left (K(\frac{z-x}{\sigma})\right )'(y_n)=-\frac{1}{\sigma}K'(\frac{z-y_n}{\sigma})$$
Now we use the hypothesis $K(z)=0$, for $|z|>1$. Hence, $K'(z)=0 $ for $|z|>1$.
So $|\frac{z-y_n}{\sigma}|\leq 1 \Rightarrow y_n-\sigma\leq z\leq y_n+\sigma \Rightarrow 2x-\sigma\leq z\leq 2x+\sigma$ (when $n$ is large enough, so $y_n$ is close enough to $x$).Therefore, we know that out of the interval $(2x-\sigma , 2x+\sigma)$ it holds that $K'(\frac{z-y_n}{\sigma})$=0. Hence:
$$\left |K'(\frac{z-y_n}{\sigma})\right|\leq M\chi_{(2x-\sigma, 2x+\sigma)}(z)$$ and this holds for all $z\in\mathbb R$ and for large enough $n\in\mathbb N$.
The function in the right is obviously integrable in $\mathbb R$ , so the dominated convergence theorem applies:
$$f_\sigma'(x)=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty }\dfrac{f_\sigma(x_n)-f_\sigma(x)}{x_n-x}=\frac{1}{\sigma}\int_\mathbb R f(z)\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty }\dfrac{K(\frac{z-x_n}{\sigma})-K(\frac{z-x}{\sigma})}{x_n-x}dz$$
$$=-\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\int_\mathbb Rf(z)K'(\frac{z-x}{\sigma})dz$$
The same process, repeated, implies that $f_\sigma\in C^\infty (\mathbb R)$

Comment: thanks for your answer. Can you explain why $K'(z)=0$ for $|z|>1$ implies $|\frac{z-y_n}{\sigma}|\le 1$ and why $y_n-\sigma\le z\le y_n+\sigma$ implies $2x-\sigma\le z\le 2x+\sigma$ (where does $2$ come from?). What is $M$?

Comment: $K'(z)=0 $ for $|z|>1 $ does not imply $\left | \dfrac{z-y_n}{\sigma}\right |\leq 1$. I just want to find an interval in which $K'(z)\neq 0 ,$ so that I will integrate only in this interval, since the rest is $0$.

So we find the interval: $$y_n-\sigma\leq z\leq y_n+\sigma$$
Now we want to find an interval independent of $n$. Since $y_n\rightarrow x$ we conclude that for large enough $n\geq n_0$, $y_n$ is very close to $x$. Therefore, I take a larger interval, for example $(2x-\sigma, 2x+\sigma)$ which contains $(y_n-\sigma, y_n+\sigma)$ for all $n\geq n_0$

Comment: Regarding $M$ , it is the bound of $K'$ , since $K'\in C^\infty(\mathbb R)$

Comment: Thanks, it gets more sense to me now!